# How to get auto completion provided by <C-N> without typing <C-N>?

Tags: autocompletion

I like the simple auto completion provided by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> but not typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> everytime to get the completion.

I would like it to work similar to how [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe) works with automatic suggestions. If possible, I would also like to cycle through the completion menu with <kbd>Tab</kbd> without losing the functionality to indent.

Comment: I want this too. Bbedit only provides it during the 30 day evaluation period :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [vim-autocomplpop](https://github.com/othree/vim-autocomplpop) plug-in, which triggers the completion menu automatically as you type.

For using "Tab" instead of Ctrl+N **in** the completion menu, you can use a simple mapping such as:

```
inoremap <expr> <Tab> pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" : "\<Tab>"
```

As an alternative, you might want to consider the [SuperTab](https://github.com/ervandew/supertab) plug-in. It doesn't really do "as-you-type" completion and requires you to use the "Tab" key to initiate completion, but it's quite powerful and it has nice features you might like. (Note that I wouldn't expect SuperTab to work well with autocomplpop, so you might be able to pick one or the other, unlikely to be able to pick both.)

Answer (score 3):

You can get completions as you type with [MUconplete](https://github.com/lifepillar/vim-mucomplete). For me the advantage over similar plugins is that it is lightweight, doesn’t have dependencies (is pure Vim script) and although it only cares about Vim native sources it works quite well if you hook an LSP to `omnifunc`.

To manually trigger the menu, MUcomplete maps Tab, but you can override that. I never use them. Once the menu is open you can navigate with Tab and Shift+Tab without problems